# Why do I get an extra null terminating character when converting from WCHAR to char?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm investigating the null termination of strings with this C code.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{
    WCHAR *wstr = argv[1];
    int wlen, len, written;
    char *strA;
    DWORD nOut = 0;

    wlen = lstrlenW(wstr);

    printf("wlen: %d\n", wlen);

    if (wstr[wlen] == 0) printf("wstr[%d] == 0\n", wlen);
    if (wstr[wlen + 1] == 0) printf("wstr[%d] == 0\n", wlen + 1);

    len = WideCharToMultiByte(GetConsoleOutputCP(), 0, wstr, wlen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    printf("len: %d chars required\n", len);

    strA = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, len + 1);
    if (!strA) return -1;

    written = WideCharToMultiByte(GetConsoleOutputCP(), 0, wstr, wlen, strA, len, NULL, NULL);
    printf("written: %d\n", written);
    strA[len] = 0; /* Null terminate the ASCII string */

    WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), strA, len, &nOut, NULL); printf("\n");

    if (strA[len] == 0) printf("strA[%d] == 0\n", len);
    if (strA[len + 1] == 0) printf("strA[%d] == 0\n", len + 1);

    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, strA);

    return 0;
}
```

If I supply an input string consisting of an even number of WCHARs, e.g. `Hello!`, I get:

```
wlen: 6
wstr[6] == 0
wstr[7] == 0 /* Where does this come from? */
len: 6 chars required
written: 6
Hello!
strA[6] == 0
strA[7] == 0 /* Where does this come from? */
```

But if I supply a string with an odd number of WCHARs, e.g. `Hello`, I only get:

```
wlen: 5
wstr[5] == 0
len: 5 chars required
written: 5
Hello
strA[5] == 0
```

Why is there be an extra null terminating character at `wstr[len+1]` and `str[len+1]`? As far as I can tell, there is not enough memory allocated for the second NUL in the ASCII string.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but why do you care what happens to be stored after the NUL terminator? After NUL, there is whatever happens to be there, be it another variable, or just garbage, or even a virtual memory address that isn't mapped and doesn't exist. Sometimes it happens to be a zero, and sometimes not.

Comment: WideCharToMultiByte can process the null terminator, but can also just process a specified number of WCHARs, like in my code above. Without explicitly terminating the string with `strA[len] = 0;`, the string doesn't seem to be terminated at all. If there is no NUL character, is that a valid string for WriteConsole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
strA = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, len + 1);
```

Valid indices `i` for `strA[i]` are `0` to `len` inclusive. This means that reading `strA[len + 1]` invokes undefined behaviour because you are reading beyond the end of the buffer.

When you invoke undefined behaviour, anything is permitted to happen. One possible outcome is that your undefined behaviour results in you reading a `char` with value `0`.

Likewise, after this

```
wlen = lstrlenW(wstr);
```

you know that valid indices `i` for `wstr[i]` are `0` to `wlen` inclusive. So again it is a mistake to read `wstr[wlen + 1]`.

Simply put, stop reading beyond the end of the buffer.

You are passing the wrong length values to `WideCharToMultiByte`. It should be:

```
UINT cp = GetConsoleOutputCP();
len = WideCharToMultiByte(cp, 0, wstr, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

and

```
written = WideCharToMultiByte(cp, 0, wstr, -1, strA, len+1, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: But what about the validity of the string, if I comment out ` strA[len] = 0;`? Compiling and running the code again shows no null terminating character.

Comment: WideCharToMultiByte won't write to strA[len] because you specified a buffer length of len.

Comment: Thanks for staying with me on this. So, when specifiying a buffer length of len, I do need to (manually) null terminate the string, correct?

Comment: No. The buffer length is `len+1`. Pass that to `WideCharToMultiByte`.

Comment: And pass -1 instead of wlen